# How to query table name without owner name for a specific user in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper, oracle19c

In Oracle19c, I created tables with SYS user so that owner name is 'SYS' for tables. And then I created a new user and grant all privilege to that user. Then log in with that newly created user, query

```
Select * from tblname
```

but

> ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

error is found but can query

```
Select * from SYS.tblname
```

Is there any way to query table name without owner name from another user?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to query table name without owner name from another user?

Certainly, there is. Create a **synonym** to that table, either private (which belongs to your schema) or public (accessible by anyone).

For example: connected as `SCOTT`, I'm creating a table and granting `SELECT` privilege to user `MIKE`:

```
SQL> show user
USER is "SCOTT"
SQL> create table scott_table as
  2  select 'Littlefoot' name from dual;

Table created.

SQL> grant select on scott_table to mike;

Grant succeeded.
```

Connect as `MIKE` and try to select from that table: without specifying owner name, it won't work:

```
SQL> connect mike/lion
Connected.
SQL> select * from scott_table;
select * from scott_table
              *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

If I precede table name with owner's name, it'll work (but you want to avoid it):

```
SQL> select * from scott.scott_table;

NAME
----------
Littlefoot
```

So, create a synonym:

```
SQL> create synonym scott_table for scott.scott_table;

Synonym created.

SQL> select * from scott_table;

NAME
----------
Littlefoot

SQL>
```

---

**However**: what you did is a **HUGE** mistake. Never, ever mess up with `SYS` user. `SYS` is special. It owns the database. It is suggested not to use it at all - create your own user which will perform "system-related" tasks and grant it the `DBA` role. Use `SYS` only when no other user can do it. Creating your own tables in `SYS` schema is something you should really avoid.

Because, as `SYS` is that special, you can "forget" you're connected as `SYS`, do something you didn't plan to and destroy your database.

Therefore, I'd suggest you not to do it. Create that table elsewhere, in some other schema, and then practice *synonyms* and stuff.